# Word that sounds like particularly?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word that sort of sounds, and smells like, particularly. I can't grasp it..

Something along the likes of "peticulity" I believe

In a sentence:

"peticulity" crafted door knob

Comment: meticulously? peculiarly? Is there an "r"? May I buy a vowel? I'll take an "a", please.

Comment: Might you be thinking of ['particularity'?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/particularity)

Comment: @ErikKowal - hilarity ensues! That sounds like an anomaly in space...

Comment: You're not being very **articulate**.

Comment: _party-cool-early_?

Comment: particlely - 'the scientist was thinking particlely about wave dynamics' - not sure about the spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

distinctively, individually, individualistically, characteristically, peculiarly, uniquely, idiosyncratically.

Comment: peculiarly, got it

Comment: @medica suggested "peculiarly" in a comment.

Comment: @GregLee - That is very gracious of you! But, comments are here today and gone tomorrow, while answers are (almost) forever. Glad your answer was accepted. ')

Comment: On the other hand, answers persist, and do people want an answer to a trivial question like this to persist?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think we both feel the same way about *that* issue. Close and delete?